Prettier case-insensitive globbing
For some tooling, I'm attempting to run a Prettier command like prettier "**/*foo*" where files such as src/foo.js and src/another/Foo.js are both matched in a case-insensitive manner.
The Prettier doc states that it uses the fast-glob tool:

Otherwise, the entry is resolved as a glob pattern using the glob syntax from the fast-glob module

fast-glob has a caseSensitiveMatch option which could help, but I'm not sure if it is able to be leveraged via the Prettier CLI/API.
Or, is there an alternative approach to get case-insensitive globbing with Prettier?
